# How are the executables in <python_dir>\python-X.X.X\scripts created?

Tags: python, windows

When I install a package via pip (on Windows), e.g. pip, one or more Windows executables are created in the `scripts` directory.

```
> PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy -Command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py' -OutFile 'get-pip.py'" 
> python get-pip.py

Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-21.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.2.4
    Uninstalling pip-21.2.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.2.4
Successfully installed pip-21.2.4

> dir ..\python-3.8.5\scripts\pip*.exe
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1837-4411

 Directory of \python\python-3.8.5\scripts

09/30/2021  08:18 AM            97,151 pip.exe
09/30/2021  08:18 AM            97,151 pip3.8.exe
09/30/2021  08:18 AM            97,151 pip3.exe
09/29/2021  03:52 PM            97,093 pipdeptree.exe
               4 File(s)        388,546 bytes
```

pip.exe, pip3.exe, and pip3.8.exe all look to be something kind of py2exe-ish with a Python script embedded in the executable.

**What is auto-creating these executables?**

The embedded script uses a shebang that has a hardcoded path to the python executable. What I intend as a portable Python distribution is being hosed by this hardcoded path (rather than just specifying `python` without a path).

Details which may or may not matter

- [WinPython 3.8.5 x86](https://winpython.github.io/)
- Windows 10 x64

Is there a way to tell pip (or whatever is creating these wrapped executables) to behave differently in this regard?

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to make portable your python interpreter with its packages and executables

Comment: I have a portable installation. I update packages with pip. It's no longer portable. I want to be able able to update/install packages and keep it portable.

Comment: The question remains that I want to control the generation of these executables (or at least know who/how they're being generated).

Comment: If you want your packages to be installed for a specific python version, you can install that using: your\particular\python -m pip install some_package

Comment: The version is not the issue. It's the "location" of python that creates problems. The absolute path to python.exe is hardcoded into script embedded in the .exe. Where's the exe coming from? That's (the beginning) of the answer to my question.

Comment: when you install the python its path is added to system's path variable. If you have multiple versions of python, the path showing first will be preferred in case same filename. In windows start menu, search "edit environment variables for your account" and open it.
You will see two boxes with variables, search and double click variable "Path" in both boxes one by one and see one of them would be containing path to python folders

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237692/discussion-between-faizan-alhassan-and-mojo).

Answer (score 1):

These files are created using py2exe whose configurations can be found in setup.py file of the project.

Refer this link for more information: https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter40_py2exe.html